# yoeman generated angular 4 application can't work in hyperledger composer

Tags: angular, hyperledger

I've deployed the tutorial-network following the hyperledger composer guide and the REST API is good to access.

Then I used yo to generate an angular 4 application running again the REST API:

```
yo hyperledger-composer:angular
```

I accessed "http://server-in-cloud:4200/", and it showed me:

```
Invalid Host header
```

Answer (score 1):

In node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js

change

if(this.disableHostCheck) return true;

to

return true;

Comment: Works. But is it ok to edit files under node_modules?